# Redis cursor always yields 0 on FT.CURSOR READ

Tags: redis

I have been trying to make cursors work with aggregations and something odd is happening.

I have a redis db with an index called `idx:cits`, where a field called timestamp is indexed as a NUMERIC. I have 12307 elements (all have a timestamp value) and when I perform

```bash
FT.SEARCH idx:cits "@timestamp:[-inf inf]" LIMIT 0 0
```

It works as expected and returns the value of 12307 (same goes to having the query as `"*"` which is expected)

The problem arises when I create a cursor using

```bash
FT.AGGREGATE idx:cits "@timestamp:[-inf inf]" WITHCURSOR COUNT 500
```

It returns 500 elements and the cursor ID, but when i execute

```bash
FT.CURSOR READ idx:cits <cursorid>
```

Always returns a 0 as array and a 0 as the new cursorID signaling that it has finished reading all elements but there are still 11.807 that match that query that have not been read. Why is this happening? No matter what COUNT i use subsequent calls to the cursor yield the same result.

Performing the aggregation as

```bash
FT.AGGREGATE idx:cits "*" WITHCURSOR COUNT 500
```

though yields a correct cursor that works as expected.

I am using the docker image redis/redis-stack:7.0.6-RC2 and have set the option `MAXSEARCHRESULTS` to `-1`

Comment: Have you tried passing count to `READ` command? eg. `FT.CURSOR READ idx cursorid COUNT 500`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug with rediSearch: https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/issues/3364